# Short Image Copying USB drives on Linux

Tags: linux, copy

Is there an application that will do a short image copy of a USB drive to another USB drive?  I need something that doesn't run off a live cd

Comment: Is this to copy files from drive a to drive b, or copy an image of drive a to drive b? There's an important difference. Otherwise a dd command should work. And what do you mean by short? Fast?

Comment: I want to do a bit-by-bit copy, and maybe you heard of it as a smart copy?  Basically it would copy only the blocks that are being used by the files, and ignore the rest of the drive

Comment: What filesystem will your USB drive have?  Most **short image copy** applications must be aware of how the filesystem stores things.

Comment: they'll be either FAT or FAT32

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to linux you can probably do this in Gparted or from the CLI

> dd if=/dev/? of=driveimage.bin

then to copy the image to the device

> dd if=driveimage.bin of=/dev/?

with ? being the USB device. Just think if = "input file" of = "output file" dd will do a dump of the raw data on the device, including the partition tables.

for windows this might work
[XXClone](http://www.xxclone.com/index.htm)

Comment: I was thinking about this, but this does the whole drive, not just the blocks that are being used.